# bzr fails on an FTP Upload

Tags: ftp, commit, bazaar, cpanel

I have a website that uses cPanel.

I created an ftp account, say called Rich, but it is created as rich@mysite.com
cPanel does this automatically.

I can FTP connect fine.  I do a checkout of the code from the exposed folder on the site with bazaar (bzr pull) fine.

When I commit, I get a failure as the commit tries the ftp upload with: Rich@mysite.com as the user.  So I have a diagnosis of case sensitivity.

I am on a Win machine and cannot for the life of me figure out how to get the bzr repo configured to accept a change to the different ftp user name.  Conversely, I do not know how to change the FTP account to make it a cap R.

I tried setting the bzr config items, but there really isn't a great example in the user docs of bzr of exactly how to do this or should I say an exact mapping of what represents what in relation to the internal workings of bzr.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

After finding myself in the same boat, I did some research and found that you can escape special characters in the Bazaar command line.  What you are having a problem with now is the double @ signs, e.g.:

```
bzr pull ftp://rich@mysite.com@mysite.com/mybranch
```

This won't work, as Bazaar will see "rich@mysite.com@mysite.com" incorrectly.  However, it *will* work, if you encode the first @ sign:

```
bzr pull ftp://rich%40mysite.com@mysite.com/mybranch
```

It will still post "password for username rich@mysite.com@mysite.com", but it will work correctly instead of failing.

Answer (score 0):

try to specify required username in the URL to your master branch as ftp://name@host.com/path

Comment: I tried that and I get the following error:  bzr: ERROR: Transport error: Error setting up connection: 530 Login authenticati
on failed 530 Login authentication failed

Comment: @Rich Elswick : Your problem is very specific to your environment. I suggest you to ask about your problem here: https://answers.launchpad.net/bzr/+addquestion or here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/bzr/+filebug